# Nested objects/forms and best practices in Vue

Tags: forms, vue.js, rest, vuejs3

I'm using Vue3 to build a form to Create/Update an **Entity**.

This **Entity** has 2 children tables: **Contacts** and **Addresses**
I have api routes for all these 3 tables.

Currently I have a single component with 3 different forms, and i'm storing the information on multiple ref variables instead of just one:

```
const entity = ref({}); //it would be binded to the form and also contain the information in case of update
const contacts = ref([]); //also binded to form and would be populated by get calls from the api
const addresses = ref([]); //same situation
```

My goal here is to make a form that could be used in both Create and Update.

The problem is that: When i'm creating an **entity** and i want to add **addresses**/**contacts** I don't have the parent id to insert them so the solution would be to store them locally and then make multiple api calls to store everything: post Entity, post multiple Addresses/Contacts.
This wouldn't be reusable as an Update form as far as I know.

So I have a couple of questions:

1. Should I make child components to handle the forms?(addresses and contacts)
2. How would you go about storing the information? One single object? One for each form?
3. What would be best option about api calls? It seems that it would be more efficient/simple to add child items on the go, instead of all at once.

Any help/tips/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your data model is

```js
{
  entity_id: unique_ID,
  entity_attribute_1: value_1,
  entity_attribute_2: value_2,
  contacts:
  [
    {
      contact_id: unique ID,
      contact_attribute_1: value_1,
      contact_attribute_2: value_2,
      addresses:
      [
        {
          address_id: unique ID,
          country_id: ...,
          city: '',
          zipCode: '',
          street: '',
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
}
```

Obviously you can not create a new address without a contact and/or a new contact without an entity. Therefore:

1. You should create child components (tables to list existing elements and modal dialogs to create/update each element)
2. The entity form will have just a single object while contacts and addresses will have an array of objects
3. The best option is to call the API only after clicking on the final SUBMIT button for the entity. It will either create a new entity (and then new contacts with new addresses) or update existing entity/contacts/addresses. Each of the objects (address/contact/entity) will have to have a `modified` flag and `deleted` flag. Then your API can accept 3 arrays of data - `created` with new addresses/contacts, `updated` with modified addresses/contacts and `deleted` with deleted addresses/contacts. Something like this:

```js
      submitForm()
      {
        const payload = {
          ...this.form,
          id: this.warrantyID,
        };
        if (this.warrantyID)
        {
          const added = [];
          const updated = [];
          const deleted = [];
          this.form.entries.forEach(row =>
          {
            if (row.deleted) deleted.push({ id: row.id });
            else
            {
              if (row.id && row.updated && row.amount) updated.push(row);
              else if (!row.id && row.amount) added.push(row);
            }
          });
          payload.insert_entries = added;
          payload.update_entries = updated;
          payload.delete_entries = deleted;
        }
        else
        {
          payload.entries = this.form.entries.filter(item => item.amount);
        }
        this.$ajax({
          method: 'POST',
          url: `/api/passive/warranty/${this.warrantyID ? 'edit' : 'add'}`,
          login: this.$root.login,
          data: payload,
          okay: (data) =>
          {
            this.close();
          },
          spinner: this.$root.showSpinner
        });
      },
```

Comment: Never thought about the usage of insert update delete flags, it seems clever. Some questions come to mind: Will the parent form handle all the sub component forms?Subcomponents emit their form payload for parent component?

Comment: Also another question, it seems to me that you are sending all the information in bulk to api. I currently have a route to post an entity, another for address. So the entity controller would have to separate the data, and insert one entity and bulk insert addresses and contacts, is that it?

Comment: Child components do not emit anything and do not perform AJAX calls - they only push/splice to the provided Array from the parent. The parent contains the logic how to make the AJAX call.

Comment: It's totally okay to have an API endpoint which updates an address by its ID.

Comment: If i use const addresses = ref([]); I will send it to the child component as a prop, and it will add delete elements as it pleases. You suggest any other way? is using a ref ok for this?

Comment: You mix different types of data  in your insert update delete entries payload right? The controller has to know which object and then do the appropriate action. You're passing the workload for the api controller, or am i getting this wrong? Any advantage to this instead iterating on the front end and making simple api post patch delete requests?

Comment: This is your application so it is your decision whether you will be making 7 simple HTTPS requests or 1 combined. I am just showing how you can create addresses when the contact does not have an ID yet and how to create contacts when the entity does not have an ID yet. Of course you may choose to implement a data model where orphan contacts and addresses are allowed - so you can first create the address and contact and only when you have the ID of the peer entity - attach them to the entity.